# Network Analyst does not take oneway street from attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, network, transportation

I want to build a network dataset to calculate travelling times for buses (service area). I have on shapefile with the streets from my home town, which has a column intitled 'ONEWAY', with values of -1 (to-from), 0, 1 (from-to), but the network is created without the oneway restrictions on those streets. Even if i try a route, for example, it is generated without taking in consideration the oneway street.
Can anyone help me understand why or what i could do?

Answer (score 3):

Your Network Dataset definition needs to include a one way restriction attribute that points to your ONEWAY column. Typically this is done with a restriction attribute that has a Field evaluator that uses the -1/0/1 value to figure out the proper directionality of the restriction.

To see an example take a look at the San Francisco sample dataset that comes with at least the ArcObjects SDK and, I think, some other products. To see the process of defining a restriction attribute, take a look at these videos: http://video.arcgis.com/watch/2111/creating-network-datasets-restriction-attributes and http://video.arcgis.com/watch/2112/creating-network-datasets-one_dash_way-streets